# How to Prevent User From Closing Putty Session while a job is running

Tags: putty

So we are using Putty to connect to our server. Sometime when a user is running a job, they would have to wait for the job to be done before they can close the session. If they close the session before the job is done, it would corrupted. I wonder is there anyway we can stop the user from closing the session when something is running.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not. Tell your clients to use the `screen` command. This will create a separate session, then you run the long-running command (batch, ...). If you're disconnected, you just have to run `screen -r` to reconnect.